# Convert only whitelisted properties from JSON to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, jackson-databind, jackson2

Want to convert incoming JSON to a `Map<String, Object>` but with the following requirements:

1. Unknow properties should not cause exceptions (`objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`).
2. Only whitelisted properties of the incoming JSON should appear in the `Map` (with the above configuration even unknown properties would be present in the `Map`).
3. The whitelisted properties should automatically correspond to the fields of a POJO.

Converting the JSON directly to my POJO would take care of points 1, 2, and 3, but I would lose the knowledge of which properties were included in the incoming JSON, that's why I want to convert to a `Map`.

Going from JSON to POJO to `Map` (let's call it *Map2*) would also work, but then any primitive fields in the POJO would have default values in *Map2*, even though they were absent in the JSON.

Put another way, I want the fields in the resultant `Map` to be the intersection of the properties of the JSON and the fields in the POJO.

For example, given the JSON:

```
{
    "name": "ABCD",
    "_email": "abcd@example.com",
    "roles": [
        "USER"
    ]
}
```

where `name` and `roles` are valid fields in the POJO (`email` is valid, but not `_email`), I want to end up with the `Map`:

```
{
    name: "ABCD",
    roles: [ "USER"]
}
```

Don't want to have to hand-code the list of valid field names for the various POJOs.

Comment: Why do you need a `Map` at all? If `JSON -> POJO -> Map` is fine for you, just go for it and don't use primitives in the POJO. Instead use the boxed wrappers (i.e. use `Integer` instead of `int`). Then you will get `null` instead of default values.

Comment: @BenjaminM that is the fall-back plan, but right now I'm trying to avoid having to heavily refactor my code base. The `Map` is required so that I can update just the affected fields rather than updating/overwriting the entire entity in the datastore: a little bit of efficiency.